# Workflow terminate event in Sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007, sharepoint-workflow

I am using SharePoint 2007 workflows for document approval process. When I terminate a workflow thats in In Progress state, I want to populate another list with the particular document information.
Is it possible to capture the terminate/cancel workflow event in Sharepoint?

Thanks!

Comment: workflow configured in UI or custom visual studio workflow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you use:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.workflow.runtime.workflowruntime.workflowterminated%28VS.90%29.aspx

An example:

http://en.csharp-online.net/First_Windows_Workflow%E2%80%94Workflow_Code_in_VB_.NET

For have a fault handling activity

http://diranieh.com/NET_WWF/FaultHandling.htm

Comment: The workflow is not being terminated by a an exception or fault.I am terminating the workflow instance manually by clicking on the link - If an error occurs or this workflow stops responding, it can be terminated. Terminating the workflow will set its status to Canceled and will delete all tasks created by the workflow. 
 **Terminate this workflow now.** What does the system exactly do when i click on the Termainte link?

Comment: If this is the case, is the solution from the link you have suggested still valid?